# Love 2D(Lua) unexpected nil in object

Tags: lua, love2d

Trying to get my feet wet with LUA and Love2D, and I am having an issue with object instantiation / access in Lua.

Source with the bug can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/dannsee/love_scrollingshooter

I am In my main, I create an object, Enemies

```
enemies = Enemies:new()
```

and inside of the enemies object, i create an object to hold peristant values, which I am calling Timers.

```
timers = Timers:new()
```

So the enemies 'constructor' method looks (basically) like this

```
Enemies = {} -- so that Enemies will not be nil when new() is called
timers = {} -- so that timers will be accessible in the class scope

function Enemies:new(enemies)
  enemies = enemies or {}
  timers = Timers:new()
  setmetatable(enemies, self)
  self.__index = self
  return enemies
end
```

while the Timers being created are looking as such

```
Timers = {} -- so that Timers will not be nil when new() is called

function Timers:new(timers)
    timers = timers or {
      miniBombTimerMax = 0.2,
      miniBombTimer = minibombTimerMax
    } 
    setmetatable(timers, self)
    self.__index = self
    return timers
end
```

But when I try to refrence one of the timers ( from inside the enemies object) , I am getting a nil value exception.

```
timers.miniBombTimer -- Produces nil exception
```

It seems to me that this should both 1. be in scope, since it is an object created inside this class, and is instantiated locally as timers = {} before it is assigned a value, and 2. not nil becuase it is being given a value in the 'constructor'. But it seems there is more going on here that I am not grasping.

I am new to Lua, which may be obvious at this point, but from what I have read about variable scope it seems that this should be valid. I don't understand why the timers are not being created with values.

Comment: Read through http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial? You didn't show the part of the code with the problem, but presumably you're not using `self`?

Comment: Your constructors are also not using `self`. I'm assuming you want `timers` to be a member of the `Enemies` class, but maybe not? Perhaps you can share a minimal example of how you intend to use this class.

Answer (score 2):

Careful with your globals! In Lua, it's very easy to accidentally set a global variable when you don't mean to, and it looks like that's exactly what's happening.

```
function Enemies:new(enemies)
  enemies = enemies or {}
  timers = Timers:new()
  setmetatable(enemies, self)
  self.__index = self
  return enemies
end
```

On the third line here, since `timers` doesn't exist as a local variable here, this value ends up getting put into a *global* variable called `timers` instead. If you want to set a property of `enemies`, you need to mention `enemies` explicitly:

```
function Enemies:new(enemies)
  enemies = enemies or {}
  enemies.timers = Timers:new()
  setmetatable(enemies, self)
  self.__index = self
  return enemies
end
```

---

Now, you write:

> But when I try to refrence one of the timers ( from inside the enemies object) , I am getting a nil value exception.

Lua doesn't really have any concept of being "inside an object" or "inside a class". In some languages, when you're writing code inside of a class, all of the class's members are in scope and you can refer to them "bare". Lua is not one of those languages; in Lua, if you want to refer to a "class member", you need to use the dot notation, explicitly stating which object you're accessing. (Or you can do the "advanced method", using `_ENV`.)

By the way...

```
timers = {} -- so that timers will be accessible in the class scope
```

From what I see in the question, this line doesn't do much; it just creates a global variable which is never used.

Also, this line in `Enemies:new`:

```
self.__index = self
```

This just sets `Enemies.__index` every time `Enemies:new` is called. This is *fine*, but you may as well just set it once:

```
function Enemies:new(enemies)
  enemies = enemies or {}
  enemies.timers = Timers:new()
  setmetatable(enemies, self)
  return enemies
end

Enemies.__index = Enemies
```